# unknown method SendMail in mailchimp 3.0

Tags: php, mailchimp

Am using mailchimp 3.0 to send mail. getting error like "unknown method sendmail". My api key end with -us13. so i changed relevant url.
This give following output when i run the below code

```
{"status":"error","code":-32601,"name":"ServerError_MethodUnknown","error":"Unknown method \"\/SendEmail\""}Status = error
```

please look below code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
require "MailChimp.php";
$apikey = 'hidenText-us13';

$to_emails = array('abc@abc.com');
$to_names = array('Name');

$message = array(
    'html'=>'hi, this is the <b>html</b> portion',
    'text'=>'hi, this is the *text* portion',
    'subject'=>'This is the subject',
    'from_name'=>'Me!',
    'from_email'=>'valid email',
    'to_email'=>$to_emails,
    'to_name'=>$to_names
);

$tags = array('WelcomeEmail');

$params = array(
    'apikey'=>$apikey,
    'message'=>$message,
    'track_opens'=>true,
    'track_clicks'=>false,
    'tags'=>$tags
);

$url = "https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/SendEmail";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close ($ch);

$data = json_decode($result);
echo "Status = ".$data->status."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of the API that doesn't support the method SendEmail.

Try updating your URL from

> https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/**2.0**/SendEmail

to

> https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/**3.0**/SendEmail

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I updated and checked. Now am getting error like {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Resource Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The resource 'Sendemail_Collection' could not be found.","instance":""}Status = 404

Comment: That code doesn't look compatible with the current API. Why not use a library that has most of this abstracted away for you like https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

Comment: can you please help?